# How to remove padding next to adjacent links?

Tags: css, padding

I cannot remove padding adjacent to a link in [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20131007155643/http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/test3.htm)

I have reduced the problem to the bare minimum so its really clear.

I could try forcing the width of the div but I want to know why having two elements side by side makes the total wider than the sum of the parts.

You can see my issue here http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/adjacent_a.png   [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>

<style type="text/css">

*
{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font:15px arial;
}

div
{
 display :inline;
 background-color:Red;
 height:18px;
}


.MenuItemMove
{
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/page_move.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  vertical-align:top;
}



</style>
</head>


<body>


<div>

      <a href="#" class="MenuItemMove"></a>
      <a href="#" class="MenuItemMove"></a>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browsers follow a set of whitespace handling rules set out in the [XHTML/HTML schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xhtml-modularization-20000105/conformance.html#s_conform_user_agent). E.g.

- Line feed characters within a block element must be converted into a space...
- A sequence of white space characters must be reduced to a single space character...

To get around it, follow the workarounds presented in the link that meder posted in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's just natural behavior for white space between inline elements. Kill the space in the html source, literally to "circumvent" this:

http://work.arounds.org/unwanted-white-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 2):

You can float the elements, since they are inline:

```
.MenuMove
{
    ...
    float: left;
}
```